# Apex interface and abstract question

Tags: apex

How to make a call to interface method from the class which implements this interface

```
public interface IA {
    void m1();
}

public abstract class A implements IA {
    void m2() {
       /*how should a call to here be made*/ 
    }
}

public class AClass extends A {
    void m1();
}
```

For example what is wrong in execute method so that I can't call methods identified in interface.

```
public class TriggerManager {
    public interface ITriggerHandler {//TriggerManager.ITriggerHandler
        void onBeforeInsert(List<sObject> newRecords);

        void onBeforeUpdate(List<SObject> oldRecords, List<SObject> newRecords, Map<ID, SObject> oldRecordsMap, Map<ID, SObject> newRecordsMap);

        void onBeforeDelete(List<sObject> oldRecords, Map<ID, sObject> oldRecordsMap);

        void onAfterInsert(List<sObject> newRecords, Map<ID, sObject> newRecordsMap);

        void onAfterUpdate(List<sObject> oldRecords, List<sObject> newRecords, Map<ID, sObject> oldRecordsMap, Map<ID, sObject> newRecordsMap);

        void onAfterDelete(List<sObject> oldRecords, Map<ID, sObject> oldRecordsMap);
    }             

    public abstract class TriggerHandler implements ITriggerHandler {
        private void execute(Boolean isBefore, Boolean isAfter, Boolean isInsert, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isDelete, 
            List<SObject> oldRecords, List<SObject> newRecords, Map<ID, SObject> oldRecordsMap, Map<ID, SObject> newRecordsMap) {
            /*
            if(isBefore) {
                if (isInsert) onBeforeInsert(newRecords);
                else if (isUpdate) onBeforeUpdate(oldRecords, newRecords, oldRecordsMap, newRecordsMap);
                else if (isDelete) onBeforeDelete(oldRecords, oldRecordsMap);
            }
            else {
                if (isInsert) onAfterInsert(newRecords, newRecordsMap);
                else if (isUpdate) onAfterUpdate(oldRecords, newRecords, oldRecordsMap, newRecordsMap);
                else if (isDelete) onAfterDelete(oldRecords, oldRecordsMap);
            } 
            */                               
        }
    }

    public static void handle(TriggerHandler handler) {
        handler.execute(
                Trigger.isBefore, 
                Trigger.isAfter, 
                Trigger.isInsert, 
                Trigger.isUpdate, 
                Trigger.isDelete,
                Trigger.old, 
                Trigger.new, 
                Trigger.oldMap,
                Trigger.newMap);
    }
}
```

What other items did I miss in this architecture?

Comment: Are you getting an error that the methods don't exist in the interface when trying to call the from the abstract class? As a guess I'd declare the unimplemented interface methods as abstract in the abstract class.

Comment: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [TriggerManager.TriggerHandler].onBeforeInsert(LIST<SObject>)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as a `Class` has **variables**, `interfaces` have **methods**.  A `class` can implement an **interface** if the `class` has all of the **interface**'s methods.  So, how is this useful?  Here's an example:

Given an interface,

```
public interface anAwesomeInterface{
    void customSave();
}
```

and classes `class1`, `class2`, and `class3` implementing `anAwesomeInterface`.

```
public class class1 implements anAwesomeInterface{
    public void customSave(){
        // however you save an instance of class1
    }
}

public class class2 implements anAwesomeInterface{
    public void customSave(){
        // however you save an instance of class2
    }
}

public class class3 implements anAwesomeInterface{
    public void customSave(){
        // however you save an instance of class3
    }
}
```

Now let's make some collections.  We can do the following:

```
class1 anExampleOf_class1 = new class1();
class2 anExampleOf_class2 = new class2();
class2 anotherExampleOf_class2 = new class2();
class3 anExampleOf_class3 = new class3();

anAwesomeInterface aai_exampleOfClass1 = new class1();
anAwesomeInterface aai_anotherExmapleOf_class2 = anotherExampleOf_class2;

list<anAwesomeInterface> anAwesomeList = new list<anAwesomeInterface>();
anAwesomeList.add(anExampleOf_class1);
anAwesomeList.add(anExampleOf_class2);
anAwesomeList.add(anotherExampleOf_class2);
anAwesomeList.add(anExampleOf_class3);
anAwesomeList.add(aai_exampleOfClass1);
anAwesomeList.add(aai_anotherExmapleOf_class2);

for(anAwesomeInterface a:anAwesomeList)
    a.customSave();  // each gets saved depending on its class's customSave method
```

Another example would be how `Account` implements `sObject`.  An Account instance can both be an Account and an sObject depending how you want to use it.

---

Interfaces define common action among classes -- or maybe it's better the other way around, classes that have common actions define an interface.

So, the idea of interfaces is knowing what actions you want to do without specifically defining the class that's using the action.

This comes in handy when you want every class to have a specific action, though each class does that action in its own way.

A good example of this is implementing a **Sharing Model** for a Salesforce Org.  Typically, every object's **Oraginization-Wide Default** will be set to `Private`, and we'll need a trigger on **every** object to manage it's sharing.  Due to the nature of the problem, we'll have to perform an different action for each DML type -- insert, update, and delete -- for each Object!   So, to streamline this, create an interface and a static method in a class called `Sharing`.

```
public class Sharing{

    public interface sharingInterface{
        void shareOnInsert(list<sObject> newList);
        void shareOnUpdate(list<sObject> newList,map<id,sObject> oldMap);
        void shareOnDelete(map<id,sObject> oldMap);
    }

    public static void sharingTrigger(string sObjectName,list<sObject> newList, map<id,sObject> oldMap,boolean isInsert,boolean isUpdate,boolean isDelete){
    sObjectType objectType=Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName);
        if(objectType==null){
            // invalid sObjectName
            system.debug(system.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'.... ERROR in Sharing.sharingTrigger('+sObjectName+',*,*,'+isInsert+','+isUpdate+','+isDelete+').  INVALID_SOBJECT_NAME: '+sObjectName);
            system.assertNotEquals(null,objectType,'.... ERROR in Sharing.sharingTrigger('+sObjectName+',*,*,'+isInsert+','+isUpdate+','+isDelete+').  INVALID_SOBJECT_NAME: '+sObjectName);
        }
        sharingInterface sharingInterfaceHelper;
        try{
            sharingInterfaceHelper=(sharingInterface )type.forName(sObjectName.replace('__c','_sharingHelper'));
        } catch(exception e){
            system.debug(system.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'.... ERROR in Sharing.sharingTrigger('+sObjectName+',*,*,'+isInsert+','+isUpdate+','+isDelete+').  ERROR: '+e);
            return;
        }
        if(isInsert)
            sharingInterfaceHelper.shareOnInsert(newList);
        if(isUpdate)
            sharingInterfaceHelper.shareOnUpdate(newList,oldMap);
        if(isDelete)
            sharingInterfaceHelper.shareOnDelete(oldMap);
    }//END sharingTrigger(list<sObject> newList,map<id,sObject> oldMap,trigger.isInsert,trigger.isUpdate,trigger.isDelete)

}
```

So, to use this interface, we need to do two things:  (1) implement the interface in an actual Class, and (2) use the method in the appropriate trigger.  Note that the method `sharingTrigger` requires the naming convention of our classes be the same name as the sObject but with the `__c` replaced with `_sharingHelper`.

What's cool about the method is that we take the string input `sObjectName` and use it to create an instance of the class we want that implements `sharingInterface` via `type.forName()`.  Then, since it's an instance of `sharingInterface`, we can only use `shairngInterface` methods, namely those defined in the interface.  (The interface **is** those methods -- it's what's the same among all classes that implement that interface)

(1) to share the sObject `Employee__c` in Sharing

```
public class Employee_sharingHelper{

    public void sharOnInsert(list<sObject> newList){
        list<Employee__c> employeeNewList = (list<Employee__c>)newList; // setting trigger context variable to a more useable list
        // do whatcha gotta to share Employee__c's on Insert 
    }
    public void sharOnUpdate(list<sObject> newList,map<id,sObject> oldMap){
        list<Employee__c> employeeNewList = (list<Employee__c>)newList; // setting trigger context variable to a more useable list
        map<id,Employee__c> employeeOldMap=(map<id,Employee__c>)oldMap;
        // do whatcha gotta to share Employee__c's on Update.  Maybe compare lookup fields, etc.
    }
    public void sharOnDelete(map<id,sObject> oldMap){
        map<id,Employee__c> employeeOldMap=(map<id,Employee__c>)oldMap;
        // do whatcha gotta to share Employee__c's on Delete
    }
}
```

Then, to use this, we simply need to add the method sharingTrigger on an Employee__c trigger.

```
public triger on Employee__c(after insert,after update,after delete){
    Sharing.sharingTrigger('Employee__c',trigger.new,trigger.oldMap,trigger.isInsert,trigger.isUpdate,trigger.isDelete);
```

Why was all of this worth it?  Well, (1) every single one of our triggers became one-liners.  (2) All logic is stream-lined, so hopefully it's easier to understand and easier to fully-test, and (3) if we had to manage sharing for another object, all we'd have to do is create another class that implements `sharingInterface` and then write the one-line trigger.  And note that to implement sharingInterface, you have to have the methods `shareOnInsert`, `shareOnUpdate`, `shareOnDelete`, so the developer is **forced** to write those methods / worry about those scenarios.  It's like a Validation Rule to enforce good/smart coding.

Answer (score 8):

In your abstract classes you will need to impliment the interface explicitly, even if you just make the required methods abstract.

E.g.

```
public interface IA {
    void m1();
}
public abstract class A implements IA {
    void m2() {
        // Call the method defined in the interface.
        m1();
    }
    // Explicitly declare the interface method that the subclass must implement
    abstract void m1();
}
public class AClass extends A {
    public override void m1(){
        // implementation of m1 here
    }
}
```